# Size of struct with optionals in swift

Tags: swift, memory, memory-management

Strange result of call `MemoryLayout<SampleStruct>.size`. it returns 41 on the following struct.

```
struct SampleStruct {
    var tt: Int?
    var qq: Int?
    var ww: Int?
}
```

That not divisible by 3! Meantime size of `Int?` is 9. How it can be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Int?` aka `Optional<Int>` is an `enum` type and requires 9 bytes: 8 bytes for the integer (if we are on a 64-bit platform) plus one byte for the case discriminator.

In addition, each integer is *aligned* in memory to its natural (8 byte) boundary, by inserting padding bytes.

So your struct would look like this in memory:

```
i1 i1 i1 i1 i1 i1 i1 i1      // 8 bytes for the first integer
c1 p1 p1 p1 p1 p1 p1 p1      // 1 byte for the first case discriminator,
                             // ... and 7 padding bytes
i2 i2 i2 i2 i2 i2 i2 i2      // 8 bytes for the second integer
c2 p2 p2 p2 p2 p2 p2 p2      // 1 byte for the second case discriminator
                             // ... and 7 padding bytes
i3 i3 i3 i3 i3 i3 i3 i3      // 8 bytes for the third integer
c3                           // 1 byte for the third case discriminator
```

That makes a total of 41 bytes.

If `SampleStruct` values are stored contiguously in an array then additional padding is inserted between the elements to ensure that each value starts on a 8-byte boundary. This additional padding is taken into account by the *stride:*

```
print(MemoryLayout<SampleStruct>.size)    // 41
print(MemoryLayout<SampleStruct>.stride)  // 48
```

You can find the gory details in the [Type Layout](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI/TypeLayout.rst) document of the Swift documentation.